# I don't get the property position yet, why is my page not scrolling? (First HTML)

Tags: html, css

My page does not scroll even when the content exceeds the page.

I've been changing the position settings of the body, html and div elements but I see no difference.

Here's the HTML:

```css
html {
  position: absolute;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

body {
  background-color: dimgray !important;
}

body div {
  position: absolute;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background-color: dimgray;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<header class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4"><img src="/Fedecocagua.png"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="Pruebah2.html" target="_blank" style="color: black">¿Quiénes somos?</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#bottom" style="color: black">Contáctanos</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring your `html` and `body` as `position:absolute`, of course the page will not scroll. Remove this declaration as below:

```
body {
    background-color: dimgray !important;
}

header {
    position:fixed;
    padding: 10px 0;
    background-color: dimgray;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

An element which is positioned `absolute` is removed from the flow of the document, thus it can be any size and will always sit outside of the document. Your `html` and `body` elements are sacred in this right; there are very few instances where you'd want to position them absolutely. Don't worry about the positioning, just create your content in `div` elements and it will scroll naturally when it exceeds the page height, like so:

```css
div {
    margin-bottom:50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut porta nisi libero, id porta lacus rhoncus id. Pellentesque rutrum molestie maximus. In eu risus id magna tincidunt commodo placerat nec quam. Sed suscipit magna risus, quis rutrum nisl fringilla eget. Ut malesuada consequat quam, non mattis odio viverra blandit. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nam ultrices nibh et congue sodales. Phasellus sem urna, aliquam id tristique non, lacinia a libero. Vivamus ac elit ligula. Phasellus et nulla viverra, ultrices nibh id, euismod quam. Sed aliquet scelerisque elit, id sodales augue.
</div>
<div>
Maecenas quis luctus odio. Vivamus in libero ligula. Proin viverra consectetur sagittis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In rutrum ligula vitae sodales tincidunt. Etiam semper, libero sed pulvinar rhoncus, justo turpis lobortis elit, vitae dapibus magna massa a dolor. Sed tempor tortor id velit sollicitudin vestibulum. Integer ac felis orci. Etiam metus felis, porta at lectus eu, aliquet pharetra tortor. Curabitur varius tortor vitae tellus suscipit pharetra. Maecenas sit amet tortor ornare, viverra augue vitae, aliquet felis. Integer accumsan dolor ac imperdiet dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Pellentesque lobortis non quam quis semper.
</div>
<div>
Curabitur ipsum risus, ultricies nec posuere at, finibus quis augue. Mauris ultrices massa quis ipsum tincidunt condimentum. Fusce feugiat id sapien non fermentum. Curabitur vel lectus laoreet velit eleifend tincidunt. Nulla tempus nisi nec lorem efficitur congue. Suspendisse laoreet arcu tempor est tempor pharetra. Sed suscipit vel lorem id elementum. Praesent vitae mauris justo. Vivamus non tellus ligula. Nunc laoreet tincidunt arcu eget maximus.
</div>
<div>
Mauris eu sagittis velit, quis vulputate ex. Vivamus pretium, urna venenatis scelerisque blandit, eros magna placerat ipsum, sit amet accumsan lacus erat non orci. Vestibulum sagittis fringilla mi, vel feugiat ante suscipit in. Sed pellentesque nulla urna, vel interdum augue placerat vitae. Fusce vitae tortor et libero tempus blandit. Donec rutrum venenatis faucibus. Proin luctus rhoncus mauris, nec dictum nisl dapibus eget. Phasellus sollicitudin orci nec augue ultrices, eu vestibulum dolor tincidunt. Integer lobortis eget nibh non ultrices.
</div>
<div>
Cras molestie lectus eget nisi mattis varius. Morbi feugiat in turpis eu fermentum. Nullam et tempus mi, eget ultricies ex. In cursus, lorem id aliquet eleifend, velit ipsum ultricies nisl, sed ultricies nisi arcu ut augue. Nulla pretium ligula et ipsum sodales, vel scelerisque est porttitor. Nulla vitae mi eget quam sodales efficitur at non ex. Fusce imperdiet orci et urna varius rutrum. Donec efficitur tellus non tempor varius. In mattis tortor non metus porttitor fermentum. Etiam dapibus quam augue, et sollicitudin sem feugiat quis. Vestibulum id tortor a elit tempus ultricies semper sit amet nunc. </div>
</div>
```

Comment: and does classes affect the divs' natural scrolling? Thanks, it was very helpful!

Comment: @AndrésIxcoyGaray simply applying a class does not affect anything unless you give it a property in your css that will do so.